# associating a GridFS-Stream file to a Schema with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, gridfs-stream

I am writing an API for my application, using Mongoose, Express, and GridFS-Stream. I have a Schema for the articles the user will create:

```
var articleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title:String,
    author:String,
    type: String,
    images: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "fs.files"},
    datePublished: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    content: String
})
var Article = mongoose.model("article", articleSchema, "articles");
```

and my grid-fs set up for when a user uploads an image:

```
api.post('/file', fileUpload.single("image"), function(req, res) {
var path = req.file.path;
var gridWriteStream = gfs.createWriteStream(path)
    .on('close',function(){
        //remove file on close of mongo connection
        setTimeout(function(){
            fs.unlink(req.file.path);
        },1000);
    })
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(path)
    .on('end',function(){
        res.status(200).json({"id":readStream.id});
        console.log(readStream);
    })
    .on('error',function(){
        res.status(500).send("Something went wrong. :(");
    })
    .pipe(gridWriteStream)
```

});

Right now it's set up to when the user chooses an image, it automatically uploads it via gridfs-stream, puts it in a temp folder, then deletes it when it is uploaded to the mongo server, and in the console returns what the ObjectId is. Well thats all find and dandy, but we need to associate this ID with the articleSchema, so when we call that article in the app, it will display the associated image.

on our creation/update of an article when the user hits submit:

```
createArticle(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var article = {
  type: this.refs.type.getValue(),
  author: this.refs.author.getValue(),
  title: this.refs.title.getValue(),
  content: this.refs.pm.getContent('html')
};
var image = {
  images: this.refs.imageUpload.state.imageString
};
var id = {_id: this.refs.id.getValue()};
var payload = _.merge(id, article, image);
var newPayload = _.merge(article, image)
if(this.props.params.id){
  superagent.put("http://"+this.context.config.API_SERVER+"/api/v1.0/article/").send(payload).end((err, res) => {
      err ? console.log(err) : console.log(res);
  });
} else {
  superagent.post("http://"+this.context.config.API_SERVER+"/api/v1.0/article").send(newPayload).end((err, res) => {
    err ? console.log(err) : console.log(res);
    this.replaceState(this.getInitialState())
    this.refs.articleForm.reset();
  });
}
```

},

So what I need it to do, is call the ID, of the image I just uploaded to the images section of my schema when the user hits submit on the creation of an article. I've tried doing a readstream on submit, but again, the problem is I can't get the ID, or the filename, to be able to associate it.

They are getting stored in the mongo database, it creates fs.files and fs.chunks, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get that data and attach it to a schema, or just even get the data out, without knowing the ObjectId.

So how do I call out the objectid from fs.files or fs.chunks to attach it to the schema? and in the schema how do I reference the fs.files or chunks? so it knows what the objectid is associated with?

I can provide anymore data, if what I have is to vague, I have a nasty habit of doing that. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up solving my problem, might not be the best solution, but it works until I can get a better solution.

in the API changed

```
res.status(200).json({"id":readStream.id});
```

to

```
res.status(200).send(readStream.id);
```

in my component, I then set the state to the response.body, which will set the state of the id of the image uploaded. So in the main view, i reference the image uploading component, and set the image state of my view to the id state of my component, and viola, I now have the id in my database, associated with the newly created article.

the problem i then ran into was, it didn't know what to reference. so I attached the API URL to the id, and it acts like it is referencing a URL img, and renders the image correctly.

Again, this may not be the best way to go about this, in fact, I am pretty sure it isn't, but It is whats working for now until I can either reference the database correctly, or create a new component that just stores all the images on server and reference them that way, much like wordpress.